# "bnr not recognised as internal command" while developing ionic2-cordova app

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, npm, ionic2

This is the error i am getting when i am trying to build android. Can anyone help?

```
'bnr' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ionic2-taxi-app@0.1.0 dev: `bnr dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ionic2-taxi-app@0.1.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\VARANASI\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-07-    01T13_14_22_953Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

In the project I'm currently working on, that error sometime occurs. Usually when some command execution fails, but I don't know exactly the cause. Anyway, it seems executing `npm install` again solves the problem.